# CORS post arguments are empty

Tags: javascript, php

i'm trying to send a post request (file upload with some informations) into a sub domain by a CORS request.
I already tried searching online but I didn't found anything that could solve my problem.

I can send the request and the log get updated, but witout any data because '$_POST' is empty.

Any help?

Uploader.php (where i send the request)

```js
const BYTES_PER_CHUNK = 94371840; // 1MB chunk 

var percentComplete = [];
var uploadingList = [];
var uploadingListPublic = [];
var startList = [];
var sizeList = [];
var endList = [];
var vid;
var pvid;

window.BlobBuilder = window.MozBlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.BlobBuilder;

function startUpload() {
  var files = document.getElementById('fileUpload').files;
  var baseLenght = getLenght() - files.length;
  $.each(files, function(key, blob) {
    var name = blob.name;
    console.log("normal: " + key);
    key += baseLenght;
    console.log("try: " + key);

    if (getStart(key) < getSize(key)) {
      console.log("started: " + key + ": " + name);
      var chunk = blob.slice(getStart(key), getEnd(key), key);
      uploadFile(chunk, getSize(key), name, key, getFileID(key), getFilePID(key));
      startList[key] = getEnd(key);
      endList[key] = getStart(key) + BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
    } else {
      console.log("already completed: " + key);
    }
  });
}

function sendRequest(e, key) {
  console.log("request: " + key);
  var blob = document.getElementById('fileUpload').files[key];
  console.log("request: " + key + " IS OK");
  var name = blob.name;


  if (getStart(key) < getSize(key)) {
    console.log("started: " + key + ": " + name);
    var chunk = blob.slice(getStart(key), getEnd(key), key);
    uploadFile(chunk, getSize(key), name, key, getFileID(key), getFilePID(key));
    startList[key] = getEnd(key);
    endList[key] = getStart(key) + BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
  } else {
    console.log("already completed: " + key);
  }
}

function fileSelected() {
  var files = document.getElementById('fileUpload').files;
  var baseLenght = getLenght();
  $.each(uploadingList, function(key, fileID) {
    if (document.getElementById('progress-bar' + key).innerHTML == '<div id="progress-status">Completed!</div>') {

    } else {
      console.log("Key: " + key);
      uploadCancelled(null, key);
    }
  });
  $.each(files, function(key, blob) {
    key += baseLenght;
    console.log("NewKey: " + key);
    percentComplete.push(0);
    startList.push(0);
    sizeList.push(blob.size);
    endList.push(BYTES_PER_CHUNK);

    vid = uniqueId() + uniqueId();
    pvid = vid + uniqueId();

    console.log("video: " + key + "\nID: " + vid + "\nPID; " + pvid);

    uploadingList.push(vid);
    uploadingListPublic.push(pvid);

    var name = blob.name;
    var fileSize = 0;
    if (blob.size > 1024 * 1024)
      fileSize = (Math.round(blob.size * 100 / (1024 * 1024)) / 100).toString() + 'MB';
    else
      fileSize = (Math.round(blob.size * 100 / 1024) / 100).toString() + 'KB';
    var type = blob.type;

    document.getElementById('FilesInfo').innerHTML += '<div id="file' + key + '"' +
      '<div id="fileName' + key + '">' + name + '</div>' +
      '<div id="fileSize' + key + '">' + fileSize + '</div>' +
      '<div id="fileType' + key + '">' + type + '</div>' +
      '<div class="progress-div" id="progress-div' + key + '"><div class="progress-bar" id="progress-bar' + key + '"></div></div>' +
      '</div><br>';
  });
}

function uploadFile(blobFile, fileSize, name, fileKey, VID, PVID) {
  console.log(name + " id: " + VID + " PID: " + PVID + "Uploading")
  var UID = '<?php echo $UID; ?>';
  var SIZE = fileSize;
  console.log("uploading: " + fileKey + " chunk");

  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append("fileToUpload", blobFile);
  fd.append("fileName", name);

  fd.append("UID", UID);

  fd.append("VID", VID);
  fd.append("PVID", PVID);
  fd.append("vSize", SIZE);


  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  /*xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
      uploadProgress(evt, fileKey);
  }, false);*/
  xhr.addEventListener("load", function(evt) {
    console.log("Completed " + fileKey + ": ")
    uploadComplete(evt, fileKey);
  }, false);
  xhr.addEventListener("error", function(evt) {
    uploadFailed(evt, fileKey);
  }, false);
  xhr.open("POST", "https://encoder.streaminto.com/upload/");
  xhr.onload = function(evt) {
    sendRequest(this.responseText, fileKey);
  };
  xhr.onerror = function(e) {
    alert("ERROR: " + e);
  }

  xhr.send(fd);
  //alert("oen over");
}

function uploadProgress(evt, fileKey) {
  if (evt.lengthComputable) {
    percentComplete[fileKey] = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / getSize(fileKey)) + Math.round((getStart(fileKey) - BYTES_PER_CHUNK) * 100 / getSize(fileKey));
    $('#progress-bar' + fileKey).css('background-color', 'green')
    $("#progress-bar" + fileKey).width(getPerc(fileKey) + '%');
    $("#progress-bar" + fileKey).html('<div id="progress-status">' + getPerc(fileKey) + ' %</div>');

    if (getPerc(fileKey) >= 100) {
      $("#progress-bar" + fileKey).width('100%');
      $('#progress-bar' + fileKey).css('background-color', 'orange');
      $('#progress-bar' + fileKey).html('<div id="progress-status">Encoding..</div>');
    }
  } else {
    $("#progress-bar" + fileKey).width('100%');
    $('#progress-bar' + fileKey).css('background-color', 'red');
    $('#progress-bar' + fileKey).html('<div id="progress-status">Error while trying to upload!</div>');
  }
}

function uploadComplete(evt, fileKey) {
  if (getPerc(fileKey) >= 100) {
    $("#progress-bar" + fileKey).width('100%');
    $('#progress-bar' + fileKey).css('background-color', 'blue');
    $('#progress-bar' + fileKey).html('<div id="progress-status">Completed!</div>');
  }
}

function uploadFailed(evt, fileKey) {
  alert("There was an error attempting to upload the file: " + getFileID(fileKey));
}

function uploadCancelled(evt, fileKey) {
  $("#progress-bar" + fileKey).width('100%');
  $('#progress-bar' + fileKey).css('background-color', 'red');
  $('#progress-bar' + fileKey).html('<div id="progress-status">Cancelled!</div>');
}

function getPerc(intFile) {
  return percentComplete[intFile];
}

function getFileN(fileID) {
  return uploadingList.indexOf(fileID);
}

function getFileID(intFile) {
  return uploadingList[intFile];
}

function getFilePID(intFile) {
  return uploadingListPublic[intFile];
}

function getSize(intFile) {
  return sizeList[intFile];
}

function getStart(intFile) {
  return startList[intFile];
}

function getEnd(intFile) {
  return endList[intFile];
}

function getLenght() {
  if (typeof uploadingList !== 'undefined' && uploadingList.length > 0) {
    return uploadingList.length;
  }
  return 0;
}

const uniqueId = () => {
  const randomness1 = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2);
  const dateString = Date.now().toString(36);
  const randomness2 = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2);
  return randomness1 + dateString + randomness2;
};
```

```css
#uploadForm {
  border-top: #F0F0F0 2px solid;
  background: #FAF8F8;
  padding: 10px;
}

#uploadForm label {
  margin: 2px;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.demoInputBox {
  padding: 5px;
  border: #F0F0F0 1px solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.progress-bar {
  background-color: #12CC1A;
  height: 20px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 0%;
  -webkit-transition: width .3s;
  -moz-transition: width .3s;
  transition: width .3s;
}

.btnSubmit {
  background-color: #09f;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  color: #FFF;
  border: #F0F0F0 1px solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.progress-div {
  border: #0FA015 1px solid;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  margin: 30px 0px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%
}

#targetLayer {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h2>
    Upload
  </h2>
  <form id='formUploader' name='formUploader' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id='FilesUpload'>
      <?php
            echo "<input type='file' id='fileUpload' name='fileUpload' accept='video/mp4,video/x-m4v,video/*' onchange='fileSelected()' multiple><br>";
    
            echo "<input type='button' onclick='startUpload()' value='Upload'/><br>";
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id='FilesInfo'>
    </div>
  </form>
</center>
```

/upload (response page)

```
<?php
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/admin/files/mysql/connection.php");


$target_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/videos/";
$tmp_name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
$fileName = $_POST['fileName'];
$UID = $_POST['UID'];

$VID = $_POST['VID'];
$PVID = $_POST['PVID'];

$VSize = $_POST['vSize'];

$target_file = $target_path . "tmp-" . $fileName;

$fp = fopen('logfile.txt', 'a');

fwrite($fp, "Method: $method \n Starting upload:\n VARS: UID: $UID | VID: $VID | VSIZE: $VSize | tmpName: $tmp_name \n\n");
fclose($fp);

// Open temp file
$out = fopen($target_file, "wb");

$fileExtension = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

$complete = $target_path . $VID . "." . $fileExtension;
$com = fopen($complete, "ab");

            $fp = fopen('logfile.txt', 'a');

            fwrite($fp, "Starting write\n");
            fclose($fp);

if ( $out ) {
    // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
    $in = fopen($tmp_name, "rb");
    if ( $in ) {
        while ( $buff = fread( $in, 94371840 ) ) {
            fwrite($out, $buff);
            fwrite($com, $buff);
        }   
    }
    fclose($in);
    fclose($out);
}
fclose($com);
            $fp = fopen('logfile.txt', 'a');

            fwrite($fp, "completed write\n");
            fclose($fp);
            $fp = fopen('logfile.txt', 'a');

            fwrite($fp, "SIZE COMP: ".filesize($complete)."/".$VSize."\n");
            fclose($fp);

if(filesize($complete) == $VSize){
                $fp = fopen('logfile.txt', 'a');

                fwrite($fp, "completed file\n");
                fclose($fp);
    unlink($target_file);
    //FILE COMPLETED
    $name = str_replace(".".$fileExtension, "", $fileName);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `videos` (`UID`, `VID`, `PVID`, `VideoName`, `dateUpload`, `size`) VALUES (:UID, :VID, :PVID, :videoN, :dateUpload, :size)";

    $stmtUpload = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $date = date(strtotime('now'));

    $stmtUpload->execute(array(
        ':UID' => $UID,
        ':VID' => $VID,
        ':PVID' => $PVID,
        ':videoN' => $name,
        ':dateUpload' => $date,
        ':size' => $VSize
    ));


    $sql = "INSERT INTO `waitingEncode` (`PVID`, `Extension`) VALUES (:PVID, :ext)";

    $stmtUpload = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $date = date(strtotime('now'));

    $stmtUpload->execute(array(
        ':PVID' => $PVID,
        ':ext' => $fileExtension
    ));
}

?>
```

[This is my NGINX configuration for Access-Control-Allow-Origin etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdN6g.png)

EDIT: I found out that it isn't really a CORS problem, i tried on the same domain and the response page POST is completly empty.
So XMLHttpRequest isn't sending the post correctly.
Any help??

Comment: Why do you use both `.onload` and `addEventListener()` for `xhr`?

Comment: PHP needs to send an `Access-Control-Allowed-Origin` response.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i figured out that the $_POST and $_FILES Where empty because of php.ini settings (max file size and max post size).
Now the problem is that when i try to get `xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress, function(){code},false);` i need to send a preflight request, but i receive error 405.

Here is the response page code:

```html
<?php
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/admin/files/mysql/connection.php");


$target_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/videos/";
$tmp_name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
$fileName = $_POST['fileName'];
$UID = $_POST['UID'];

$VID = $_POST['VID'];
$PVID = $_POST['PVID'];

$VSize = $_POST['vSize'];

$target_file = $target_path . "tmp-" . $fileName;

$fp = fopen('logfile.txt', 'a');

fwrite($fp, "Method: $method \n Starting upload:\n VARS: UID: $UID | VID: $VID | VSIZE: $VSize | tmpName: $tmp_name \n\n");
fclose($fp);

// Open temp file
$out = fopen($target_file, "wb");

$fileExtension = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

$complete = $target_path . $VID . "." . $fileExtension;
$com = fopen($complete, "ab");

            $fp = fopen('logfile.txt', 'a');

            fwrite($fp, "Starting write\n");
            fclose($fp);

if ( $out ) {
    // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
    $in = fopen($tmp_name, "rb");
    if ( $in ) {
        while ( $buff = fread( $in, 94371840 ) ) {
            fwrite($out, $buff);
            fwrite($com, $buff);
        }   
    }
    fclose($in);
    fclose($out);
}
fclose($com);
            $fp = fopen('logfile.txt', 'a');

            fwrite($fp, "completed write\n");
            fclose($fp);
            $fp = fopen('logfile.txt', 'a');

            fwrite($fp, "SIZE COMP: ".filesize($complete)."/".$VSize."\n");
            fclose($fp);

if(filesize($complete) == $VSize){
                $fp = fopen('logfile.txt', 'a');

                fwrite($fp, "completed file\n");
                fclose($fp);
    unlink($target_file);
    //FILE COMPLETED
    $name = str_replace(".".$fileExtension, "", $fileName);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `videos` (`UID`, `VID`, `PVID`, `VideoName`, `dateUpload`, `size`) VALUES (:UID, :VID, :PVID, :videoN, :dateUpload, :size)";

    $stmtUpload = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $date = date(strtotime('now'));

    $stmtUpload->execute(array(
        ':UID' => $UID,
        ':VID' => $VID,
        ':PVID' => $PVID,
        ':videoN' => $name,
        ':dateUpload' => $date,
        ':size' => $VSize
    ));


    $sql = "INSERT INTO `waitingEncode` (`PVID`, `Extension`) VALUES (:PVID, :ext)";

    $stmtUpload = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $date = date(strtotime('now'));

    $stmtUpload->execute(array(
        ':PVID' => $PVID,
        ':ext' => $fileExtension
    ));
}

?>
```

Here is NGINX config file:

```
server {
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "OPTIONS, GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, PATCH, HEAD";
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, application/octet-stream, text/html, X-PINGOVER, Session";

client_max_body_size 20000m;
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;

# SSL configuration
listen 443 ssl default_server;
listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    root /var/www/Streaminto;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name encoder.streaminto.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        rewrite embed/(.*)$ /embed/index.php?videoPID=$1 last;
        rewrite playlist/(.*)$ /playlist/index.php?playlistPID=$1 last;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

And this is the browser network page:
[image: Network]

[image: Cors Error]

[image: Error 405]
[image: Error 405/2]